# How to disable evaluation of parameters in a method

Tags: c#, logging, .net-4.0

Couldn't remember better title, feel free to change it to something better :)

My application contains a lot of logging statements, something like this:

```
var logger = new Logger(/*..get flag from settings if the logger should be active..*/);
// ....
logger.LogActivity(..serialize an object..);
//...
logger.LogActivity(..get another object's expensive overriden ToString method..);
//...
logger.LogActivity(..log something new..);
```

Logger class:

```
public class Logger
{
  private readonly bool _isActive;

  public Logger(bool isActive)
  {
    _isActive = isActive;
  }

  public void LogActivity(string activity)
  {
    if (_isActive)
    {
      // Save activity to Database.
    }
  }
}
```

When I disable logger in settings (so the _isActive field in Logger class is false), then nothing is saved to database. But all the expressions in the Logger.LogActivity methods are still evaluated (for instance ..serialize object.. in previous example) and this slows down my application. 
I could use log statements like this:

```
var logger = new Logger(/*..get flag from settings if the logger should be active..*/);
// ....
if (loggerIsActive) logger.LogActivity(..serialize an object..);
//...
if (loggerIsActive) logger.LogActivity(..get another object's expensive overriden ToString method..);
//...
if (loggerIsActive) logger.LogActivity(..log something new..);
```

But it would be much better to change only LogActivity method... Is it possible to somehow change only LogActivity method so that in case, when the logger is disabled, the expressions in LogActivity call aren't evaluated? Well - I would be surprised if this is possible in C#, but is there any other way/pattern to do this?

Comment: why don't you have a method like IsLoggerActive which checks whether logger is active or not and then commences logging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add an overload that takes a `Func<string>` that would generate the string to be logged.

```
public void LogActivity(Func<string> activity)
{
    if (_isActive)
    {
        string log = activity();
        // save 'log' to database
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
logger.LogActivity(() => expensiveObject.ToString());
```

Comment: This will result in most ugly code - I don't envy anybody reading logging code with all those lambda expressions.

Comment: Yes, but the question was about how to not evaluate the parameters to the function since that was an expensive operation not always needed to be performed. This creates a lambda at compile time that you can decide at runtime if to evaluate.

Comment: By doing this, at least with most modern loggers and not a custom one, you'd lose any context information like which thread, class, and line the statement was made from.

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid the parameter evaluation altogether, no, but you can provide some additional logging methods that can help you out here.

@Martin and @kenny suggested passing lambda expressions. This will defer the evaluation of the code, but will result in ugly client code. You might save a few cycles, but I doubt it would be worth it.

I suggest you create several LogActivity overrides:

```
LogActivity(string message) // logs the message
LogActivity(object obj) // calls obj.ToString() and logs it
```

And keep the lambda expression variant, if you think it's really necessary:

```
LogActivity(Func<String> func) // evaluates the function and logs its response
```

Note, you won't be able to avoid the cost of calling LogActivity. C# isn't C, and you don't have macros that work the way they do in C. That's hardly a problem, if calling a non-virtual method is expensive for you, you're doing it so often you shouldn't place log messages in there, anyway.